# Change picture of image button when mouse is over it(android)

Tags: android

How can i change the image of image button when mouse or finger is over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a Selector as the `background` of the `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 0):

On touch screen devices, there is no `:hover` attribute like web pages have (i.e. when your mouse hovers over a link, the button changes color or something). This is because there is no mouse. Your finger is either pushing down on something (like a button), or it's not.

However you can detect the different states of touching the screen. Android can tell you when someone is pushing their finger *down* on the screen, *lifting* their finger up from the screen, or *moving* their finger around on the screen, etc.

Use an [Event Listener](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) to detect when someone touches the screen, then check what the specific [motion](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) was. Update your view accordingly. The example code from those links, should be enough to get you started :)